# Can't kill node process with PID 1 in docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, kill-process

I'm new to docker. I have a docker container using `FROM node:14-alpine`. I'm using it to run a web app so I don't have to install its dependencies on my host machine. When I start the container and `docker exec my-container ps -a` I get:

```
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 node
   18 root      0:00 ps -a
```

When I `kill -9` and `ps -a` (using `docker exec`) again, I get the same output. Same thing happens for `docker killall node`. However if I start up some other node processes, I am able to successfully kill those.

Why can't I kill the node process with PID 1? I believe node starts when the container starts because of the `CMD [ "node" ]` line at the end of the `node:14-alpine` Dockerfile; what should I do if I don't need `node` to start immediately? You can find the github repo for my project [here](https://github.com/GuyMichaely/fiction-forge/tree/master).

Answer (score 1):

Docker starts it's main RUN process on PID 1. And that's indeed a special one which cannot be killed (easily).

[This article](https://blog.ghaiklor.com/2018/02/20/avoid-running-nodejs-as-pid-1-under-docker-images/) has it explained, and recommends using [Tini](https://github.com/krallin/tini) to let that spawn your process on another PID. Problem should be solved using that.